how to use touch command in windows to create multiple files with different name
I wanted to create 5 different files using touch command in windows 11 and the command i used for it was touch signUpSchema.ts verifySchema.ts signInSchema.ts acceptMessageSchema.ts messageSchema.ts
The problem I am facing is that the command is only creating the first file and leaves the rest of the file I also tried
touch signUpSchema.ts,verifySchema.ts,signInSchema.ts,acceptMessageSchema.ts,messageSchema.ts but it is creating one file with all the filenames is there some other way to solve this.
